# Custom Twitter Button with Dynamic Content and Popup Window

Tags: javascript, dynamic, twitter, xhtml, popup

I am using the following code which does 2 out of the 3 things I want it to do, shares dynamic content with a custom twitter button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // <![CDATA[
            var twtTitle = document.title;
            var twtUrl = location.href;
            var maxLength = 140 - (twtUrl.length + 1);
            if (twtTitle.length > maxLength) {
                twtTitle = twtTitle.substr(0, (maxLength - 3)) + '...';
            }
            var twtLink = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(twtTitle + ' ' + twtUrl);
            document.write('<a href="' + twtLink + '" target="_blank"' + '><img src="images/twitter.png"  border="0" alt="Tweet This!" /' + '><' + '/a>');
            // ]]>

        </script>
```

What I would like it to do is also popup in a window rather than a full page view. My knowledge of script is limited so I don't know where to insert the appropriate popup code.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of document.write you need window.open. Make sure the event is done in a click action, otherwise popup blockers would stop your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbs_click() {
    var twtTitle = document.title;
    var twtUrl = location.href;
    var maxLength = 140 - (twtUrl.length + 1);
    if (twtTitle.length > maxLength) {
        twtTitle = twtTitle.substr(0, (maxLength - 3)) + '...';
    }
    var twtLink = 'http://twitter.com/home?status=' + encodeURIComponent(twtTitle + ' ' + twtUrl);
    window.open(twtLink);
}
</script>
```

And in your HTML add your image tag like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fbs_click();" ><img src="images/twitter.png"  border="0" alt="Tweet This!"></a>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi there. Again my knowledge of javascript is extremely limited so i don't know exactly how to do this. I tried the following:

'code'<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    function fbs_click() {
     var twtTitle = 

     ... 

+ twtUrl);
     window.open('<a href="' + twtLink + '" target="_blank"' + '><img src="images/twitter.png"  border="0" alt="Tweet This!" /' + '><' + '/a>');
     return false;
    }
    // ]]>
    
   </script> 

But this didn't seem to work. Can you see anything wrong in this amendment? Thanks heaps. Pia

Comment: Sorry am new to this website and its formatting. Also i cut out the middle portion of the code to fit it in. :) @albattran

Comment: Hi there. I tried out the updated code, however my original problem remains. It opens to a full size window. How can i specify the height and width of the new window? Thanks again. Pia @albattran

Comment: oh, I see. try window.open(twtLink,'','width=300,height=300')

Comment: Oh that's fantastic. Thank you! One final thing before i leave you in peace. :) Is there any way to center this new window? Pia @albattran

Comment: Yes, you can try   var x = screen.width/2 - 300/2;
var y = screen.height/2 - 300/2;
window.open(twtLink, '','height=300,width=300,left='+x+',top='+y);

Answer (score 0):

You can place an ID="twitPop" on the anchor and use this as well.

```
$('#twitPop').click(function(event) {
    var width  = 575,
    height = 400,
    left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
    top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
    url    = this.href,
    opts   = 'status=1' +
             ',width='  + width  +
             ',height=' + height +
             ',top='    + top    +
             ',left='   + left;
    window.open(url, 'twitter', opts);
    return false;
});
```